# Инсталяционный пакет

Tags: delphi

Возник вопрос, при создании установочного пакета для проги.
Использую installshield wizard.
Имеется БД, типа Paradox.
При создании пакета, как обычно выбирается путь к файлам с базой. Не знаю где указать алиас(STANDARD) для бд?
Подскажите или посоветуете, что почитать?

Answer (score 1):

В проекте InstallShield открываем в дереве Specify Application Data-> Objects/Merge Modules, находим в списке модулей BDE, ставим галку, указываем путь к существующему файлу конфигурации или создаем новый... В этом файле конфигурации создаем необходимые алиасы.

Comment: мерси, очень помог))